# Why is port 444 open on this router?

Tags: cisco, port-forwarding, nmap

I have a Cisco RV110W. I ran nmap at it from the outside and nmap reports that the router has tcp port 444 open. Yet there are no port forwarding rules specifying this port. It should as far as I can tell, be closed. There's even a service listening to that port which I can connect to through telnet. I threw some SNPP commands at it but the service doesn't respond to any of them so I don't believe it's SNPP.

Does anyone have any idea why this particular router has tcp port 444 open? I haven't been able to find anything in the manual or on Cisco's website.

Answer (score 3):

Windows SharePoint Services could be opening that port thru uPNP.

Answer (score 3):

That port's opened because someone opened it, simple as that.

It's purpose is really anyone's guess - as you mentioned, 444 is the standard port for Simple Network Paging Protocol, and that's it.  My next guess would be that it's a secondary `https` server, given that the standard port for that is 443, and people often get lazy and just increment the port when they need to duplicate a service on the same hast.

So try connecting to it via web browser, using `https` and see what happens.

If all else fails, you can always close it and see what breaks/who screams.  I tend to favor that approach, but I do love the sound of users screaming, so maybe that's way.